# return values where key contains this string

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    [root_1] => array(
        [level_1] => array(
            [id_1] => array(
                [foo] = bar
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Where I know the names (i.e root, level and id) but I do not know the number part of the key.

I need a function that can return any parts of the array where the key contains a given name.

Cheers

Comment: What specific part you want to return or just want value index to be returned?

Comment: looke at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php if you want just index

Comment: I need to return the id_x array's once I've got level_x (which I already have for level by other means)

Comment: Does anyone know if array_keys will let me get matches like this?

Comment: Ok I have solved this issue by restructing my array in the first place. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
function search_incomplete ($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveArrayIterator ($haystack), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $key => $value)
    {
        if (strpos ($key, $needle) === 0)
        {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}

$array = array (
    'root_1'    => array (
        'level_1'   => array (
            'foo'   => 'bar',
        ),
    ),
);


var_dump (search_incomplete ('level', $array));
var_dump (search_incomplete ('root', $array));
var_dump (search_incomplete ('foo', $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$level = 1;
if (isset($array['root_'.$level]['level_'.$level]['id_'.$level])) {
    return $array['root_'.$level]['level_'.$level]['id_'.$level];
} else {
    // something else
}
```

**Edit:** If you only know the prefixes of the keys:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1)
    if (is_array($value1) && strpos($key1, 'root_') === 0)
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
            if (is_array($value2) && strpos($key2, 'level_') === 0)
                foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
                    if (strpos($key3, 'id_') === 0)
                        $out[$key1][$key2][$key3] = $value3;
return $out;
```

Comment: Alais, that wouldn't work as I cannot predict the number in advance of getting the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_search` to do this !

Comment: How? I don't know any values in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
function preg_grep_keys( $pattern, $input, $flags = 0 )
{
    $keys = preg_grep( $pattern, array_keys( $input ), $flags );
    $vals = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
    {
        $vals[$key] = $input[$key];
    }
    return $vals;
}
```

From... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#95787